# Cannot find type definitions for underscore and meteor

Tags: angular, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor, ionic-cli

I am going through the ionic and meteor integration with webpack tutorial from [angular-meteor.com](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup)

However no matter what I try I keep getting these two errors. I have tried installing typings with npm, searching google, or finding similar errors but non was really helpful. 
NOTE. I installed types for underscore and meteor-typings but still get the same error. I could really use help. I get this error on windows 10 64bit pc, running latest stable node js, npm and ionic cli.

```js
typescript error
Cannot find type definition file for '@types/underscore'.

typescript error
Cannot find type definition file for 'meteor-typings'.
```

Comment: I guess you should provide typings in tsconfig.json if you are not using the npm ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install meteor typings:

```
meteor npm install @types/meteor —save-dev
```

And add it to tsconfig.json into the types array.

Comment: Yap this definately solved the problem. Cant believe I didnt try this earlier